# awk to add 0 to print statement if condition not met

Tags: awk

In the `awk` below I setup a `loop` to read in each file of a certain type. The examples below are the two types of files but if there is nothing to count (file1 is an example) then I get no output. I am trying to print an output based on either condition, if there is none the a `0` is printed in front of the `MAPD above QC Detected`. If there is something to count then the `awk` executes as expected but I can not seem to adjust it correctly.  Both files are `tab-delimited` and the `...` represent the first three lines that are skipped.  Thank you :).

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' 'FNR == 3 {next}; $2 ~/MAPD>0.5/ {count++} END{print count " MAPD above QC Detected"}' file1 | awk '$1 == " MAPD above QC Detected" {print "0 MAPD above QC Detected"}'
```

**file1**

```
....
....
.... 
chr1:1234   foo,bar
chr2:5678   foo,bar
```

**file2**

```
....
....
....
chr1:1234   foo,MAPD>0.5
chr2:5678   foo,bar
```

desired output

**file1**

```
0 MAPD above QC Detected
```

**file2**

```
1 MAPD above QC Detected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `print count` to `print count+0`.

As an uninitialized variable, `count` has the initial value of zero-or-null and when you don't perform any arithmetic operations on it (as occurs when nothing matches in your input) then awk doesn't know you want it's numeric value 0 printed and instead prints its string value of NULL.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help an great explanation, I appreciate them :).